# Why is the IPv6 link-local address not /9?

Tags: ipv6, ip-address, ip-link-local

According to [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51170/why-is-an-ipv6-link-local-address-a-10), it's because computers read addresses in binary.

Fine. That explains why the fe80 address does not need to be /12 or /16--it's because everything after the 10th bit is a zero anyways.

```
fe80::/16 = 1111 1110 1000 0000

fe80::/12 = 1111 1110 1000

fe80::/10 = 1111 1110 10
```

But if that's the case, then why not go further and strip that last zero and get:

```
fe80::/9  = 1111 1110 1
```

EDIT: corrected formatting of IPv6 addresses, from fe80/16 to fe80::/16.

Comment: The tenth bit needs to be zero, so that's why it's a /10

Comment: Thanks @RonTrunk. But that is exactly my question--why does there need to be a tenth bit that is zero?

Comment: The designers of the addressing scheme designed it that way.  The tenth bit is zero so you can distinguish it from a specific /11. They could have picked a different scheme, but this is what they chose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It goes back to the original IPv6 addressing RFC. That 10th bit was used to distinguish between Link-Local and the (now obsolete) Site-Local addressing. If the bit was `0`, then it was a Link-Local address, and if the bit was `1`, it was a Site-Local address. Site-Local addresses were deprecated in favor of Unique-Local addresses to avoid the problems of companies merging or trying to create extranets with overlapping addressing.

*[RFC 1884, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1884)* was the original RFC where the Site-Local addressing was defined and carried through two subsequent RFCs ([RFC 2373](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2373) and [RFC 3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513)):

> **2.4.8 Local-use IPv6 Unicast Addresses**
>
> There are two types of local-use unicast addresses defined. These are
> Link-Local and Site-Local. The Link-Local is for use on a single link
> and the Site-Local is for use in a single site. Link-Local addresses
> have the following format:
>
> ```
> |   10     |
> |  bits    |        n bits           |       118-n bits           |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> |1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a
> single link for purposes such as auto-address configuration, neighbor
> discovery, or when no routers are present.
>
> Routers MUST not forward any packets with link-local source addresses.
>
> Site-Local addresses have the following format:
>
> ```
> |   10     |
> |  bits    | n bits  |    m bits     |       118-n-m bits         |
> +----------+---------+---------------+----------------------------+
> |1111111011|    0    |   subnet ID   |       interface ID         |
> +----------+---------+---------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Site-Local addresses may be used for sites or organizations that are
> not (yet) connected to the global Internet. They do not need to
> request or "steal" an address prefix from the global Internet address
> space. IPv6 site-local addresses can be used instead.  When the
> organization connects to the global Internet, it can then form global
> addresses by replacing the site-local prefix with a subscriber prefix.
>
> Routers MUST not forward any packets with site-local source addresses
> outside of the site.

The latest version is *[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)*, which obsoleted the previous RFCs, and it deprecated the Site-Local addressing:

> **2.5.6.  Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses**
>
> Link-Local addresses are for use on a single link. Link-Local
> addresses have the following format:
>
> ```
> |   10     |
> |  bits    |         54 bits         |          64 bits           |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> |1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a
> single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration,
> neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present.
>
> Routers must not forward any packets with Link-Local source or
> destination addresses to other links.
>
> **2.5.7.  Site-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses**
>
> Site-Local addresses were originally designed to be used for
> addressing inside of a site without the need for a global prefix.
> Site-local addresses are now deprecated as defined in [[SLDEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#ref-SLDEP)].
>
> Site-Local addresses have the following format:
>
> ```
> |   10     |
> |  bits    |         54 bits         |         64 bits            |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> |1111111011|        subnet ID        |       interface ID         |
> +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> The special behavior of this prefix defined in [[RFC3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513)] must no
> longer be supported in new implementations (i.e., new implementations
> must treat this prefix as Global Unicast).
>
> Existing implementations and deployments may continue to use this
> prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:

Because link-local addresses are not the only addresses starting with `111111101`:

The no-longer used "site-local" addresses (`fec0::/10 ) also started with this sequence.

So the range `fe80::/9` covers both link-local and site-local addresses.